# Do you know any dynamic instrumentation tool for Android with multi-device support (ideally in Python or Jython)?

Tags: android, jython, instrumentation, robotium, monkeyrunner

For my CI infrastrucure I need to automatically deploy and run complex tests between two (or more) android phones from a controler machine (linux).

So far android monkeyrunner in combination with android unit tests is not a satisfactory solution:

- monkeyrunner does not call single methods from a remote app and can't address UI components by their id
- writing java tests cases with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is too expensive (loC) and does not provide enough flexibility for interacting between two devices
- robotium.org is a step in the right direction but is in java (not dynamic) and not multidevice yet
- all other solutions I found does not allow interactive testing thx to dynamic scripting

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called AndroidViewClient which extends the usability of monkeyrunner. You can address UI components by ID with it, check their properties and so on.

Here's the link:
https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at MonkeyTalk?

Here:

http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk